# How to get execution time on DB Fiddle?

Tags: mysql, sql, fiddle

Hi I have query built on DB Fiddle, MySql 8.0 and I want to see the execution time. I am not sure how to do this on this tool. Can someone help for the query below?

```
select a.e_id from 
(
select *,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION by e_id ORDER BY start_date desc)rk,
count(*) over(partition by e_id) as company_ct
from employment
order by e_id asc,start_date desc
)a
where a.rk=1 and a.company_ct>1;
```

Comment: Run it on http://db-fiddle.com that gives execution times

Comment: @Nick that is the exact tool I am using...can you help me with the command on how to add code to get the execution run time please?

Answer (score 0):

As @Nick said it's displayed within the db-fiddle interface; for example the screenshot below shows an execution time of 1ms. Not sure why you would need to add any additional code?

[image: db-fiddle example]